# Rails realizando request XHR no carregamento das páginas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paginação, rotas

Tenho notado que em toda troca de página/rota, o **Rails** *faz uma nova requisição **Ajax** para buscar estes novos dados (HTML), e assim, realizar a troca da página. Fiz várias pesquisas mas o mais próximo que cheguei foi em relação ao `Embedded Ruby` ([erb](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)).

Se isso é realmente válido, gostaria de saber como e com o que o **Rails** faz essa troca, e quais as opções e vantagens de se utilizar este tipo de recurso, por exemplo:

- Tenho a disponibilidade da técnica de `two-way data binding` também?
- Quais os recursos disponíveis?
- Tenho outras opções?

## Detalhes

A pergunta pode ser confusa por isso resolvi adicionar algumas imagens que mostram o que eu realmente quero entender. Utilizando uma simples barra de navegação com links (elemento a) para a troca de rotas, como mostrado na figura 1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Figura 1: O menu de navegação que utilizei para os testes.*

Consigo notar que o rails faz algumas requisições para trocar estas páginas (como, por exemplo, o angularjs ou o vuejs faz), como mostra a imagem 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Figura 2: Os resultados das trocas de páginas/rotas na aba console.*

Conseguimos acompanhar também pela aba `network`, como mostra a figura 3.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Figura 3: Os resultados das trocas de páginas/rotas na aba network.*

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que esses requests que você está logando em seu serviço estão sendo realizados pelo [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks)(Adicionado na versão 4 do framework), infelizmente não tem `Two Way databind`, pois sua função é outra. Você pode consultar os recursos disponíveis e outras opções na [documentação do Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks).

**Um resumo geral de como ele funciona:**

Os *Turbolinks* transformam aplicações **Rails** em uma aplicação *JavaScript* de única página; ou seja, ao invés de carregar páginas novas, substitui a página atual com novo conteúdo do servidor:

> A funcionalidade é parecida com o [pjax](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/pjax/), mas no lugar de se preocupar
>   com qual elemento substituir na página e depois customizar a resposta
>   do servidor de acordo com a resposta, substituímos todo o corpo da
>   página. Com isso obtém-se a maior parte da velocidade obtida
>   utilizando pjax (sem recompilar JavaScript ou CSS), evitando
>   customizar as respostas do servidor.

Comment: Excelente! Como estou seguindo um livro para aprender Rails, não consegui identificar este recurso, que, ficou bem claro após a sua resposta e as imagens que eu mesmo adicionei a pergunta. Obrigado, tenha um bom dia de desenvolvimento.

Comment: @RafaelBerro realmente, depois de colocar as imagens consegui identificar o que realmente estava acontecendo. Bom desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

O Ruby on Rails é um framework para o backend e portanto não é um framework de single-page application (para o frontend) como AngularJS e React. Quando você requere uma rota do servidor (request), ele manda uma resposta (response), que é uma nova página com o template relacionado a rota que você pediu. (Nota: se for uma API, o servidor manda uma resposta em JSON em vez de HTML).

As rotas são configuradas em `config/routes.rb` e os templates são escolhidos baseados nas actions no controller (`app/controllers/`) que é associado com a rota. *Side note*: Muitas coisas são feitas para você behind the scenes com o Rails, então se você quiser entender mais o negócio de rotas e templates, eu sugiro você usar o [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), que é um web framework parecido com o Rails, embora muito mais light e requere você faça suas próprias rotas e mande os templates manualmente.

Acho que você está confundindo o frontend com o backend. Normalmente os dois são separados e o Rails só serve de um backend que manda informações via JSON. Aí no frontend, usando um framework como o Angular, você faz requests para o backend para obter as informações via JSON, que você põe no DOM. É no frontend que você pode fazer two-way data binding (com o Angular) ou one-way (com o React).

Comment: Agradeço por compartilhar estas informações, mas infelizmente essa não é a resposta que procuro. Adicionei algumas informações e imagens na questão, se você der uma olhada e conseguir me responder novamente eu agradeço. Abraços.